# nodejs setTimeout and recursive calls context (this/self)

Tags: node.js, recursion, promise, stream, settimeout

Im currently working on a project and got stuck at the *setTimeout()* function in a recursive function. Im rather new to promises so may i did implement this part not corretly too.

The programm should do:

1. add a listener to a stream event 'readable'
2. write a request to the stream if specific periodic data is read
3. resolve promise and remove listener after some other data (answer) is 
   recieved
4. Send message from Stream to another process
5. repeat by calling the same method recursivly with a delay of 10secs

Bassicly im trying to poll from a stream every 10 seconds.

The code looks simplyfied like this:

```
    class XYZ {
        myFunction(commands, intervall, i) {
            var self = this;

            var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                // I have to write to a Stream and listen for an answer
                self.dataStream.write(someData, () => {
                    self.dataStream.addListener('readable', handleStuff);
                });

                // Function that handles incoming data from the Stream
                var handleStuff = function () {
                    if (self.dataStream == someFormat) {
                        self.dataStream.write(commands[i]);
                    } else {
                        self.dataStream.removeListener('readable', hadleStuff);
                        resolve(self.dataStream.read());
                    }
                }
            });

            // Resolving by sending msg and calling recursivly
            promise.then((message) => {
                self.send(message);
                if (i + 1 > resetValue) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        self.myFunction(commands, intervall, 0);
                    }, intervall);
                } else {
                    self.myFunction(commands, intervall, i + 1);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

And i call it like this:

```
var myXYZ = new XYZ();
myXYZ.myFunction(myCommands, 10000, 0);
```

Now when i run this the initial call, it works just fine and sends the message from the dataStream to another process. But when the *setTimeout()* function is called the function gets "stuck" after writing data to the stream for the first time and the promise is not resolved neither rejected. 
My guess is that im mixing up the context (this/self) in my code. Theres sadly no error message, so that i think my logic is faulty. It also works fine if i just remove the *setTimeout()* function. My Question now is how does *setTimeout()* change the context from which the code operates?

Comment: The logic about exactly when the `readable` event is triggered is really complicated (just look internally at the stream source to see how messy it is).  I would guess that you're waiting for a readable event, but the stream thinks it already notified about the data that is here, but you removed that event handler.  Or perhaps you didn't read everything that was already in the buffer so it's waiting for the buffer to be cleared.

Comment: Because of these complexities with the readable event, the doc contains this: ***"In general, it is recommended that developers avoid the use of the 'readable' event and the readable.read() method in favor of using either readable.pipe() or the 'data' event."***

Comment: Note also that `self.dataStream.read()` is not guaranteed to read everything that is available.  To do that, you have to loop until you get `null`.

Comment: Also, is this stream paused so that it won't flow automatically when data arrives?  From the doc: ***"The readable.read() method should only be called on Readable streams operating in paused mode. In flowing mode, readable.read() is called automatically until the internal buffer is fully drained."***

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was that the program got stuck in an endless loop after removing and adding an event listener. "[...] readable.read() is called automatically until the internal buffer is fully drained." Somehow the buffer after removing and adding a listener never got fully drained so the program could not continue. I changed the event to 'data' and it immediately worked.